# How to minimize the size of a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I was creating a flutter app without adding any thing to it and try launching it. 
The problem is, size of the flutter app that was created is **65.88MB**

Are these the flaws of flutter or not?

Comment: You might be checking the file size of a debug build. If so, don't worry about that much, the file size of a plain app in Flutter is actually only around 4.7MB in release build.

Answer (score 2):

Flutter apps may be larger in file size than native apps, but not that much according to my experience. I've built a fully-featured app with firebase and some in-app-database like SQLite with most of the apps under the file size of 6 or 7MB. If I would not split per ABI, then the app would probably around 12 or 13MB. But for most of the apps that you're actually launching, you would want to split per ABI.

According to your question, you might be checking the application's file size of the debugging build. The debug application's file size would normally be large because it has lots and lots of components to make your development smooth and faster, for example, the ability to hot-reload during debugging.

What you would want to do is to build a release version of the app by doing,

```sh
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

which should yield a release version of the app, with the file size around 5MB which normally is the file size of a hello world application in Flutter. You can learn more about building the release application [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you should give this a try, sometimes what happens is, you don't clear out your previous data and try to build the `apk`, which gives out more heavy file.

Always follow the below steps, and you will get a lighter file in respect of size.

Go to your console **->** go inside your project directory **->** type the following:

```
 1. flutter clean
 2. flutter build apk --release
```

- Now what the above command does, `flutter clean`, cleans up the previous data stored in the build file. Deletes `build` file
- `flutter build apk --release`, builds the android apk in the `release` mode. It is generally lighter than the `debug` mode.

For more info on releasing the Android installation file, please follow this: [Building Flutter Android App](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

Comment: **Thanks Alok . but when execute the second one command return some errors like this :**

'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.'

Comment: Hey @AbdulmajeedNajiAlshari, for that you might look into that yourself, **raise a question or google your problem**. The above code works totally for everyone, it is some kind of build failure you are facing. Let me know when you get the smaller size `apk` with my answer, you can upvote it anytime.